# Intel p-state is global setting or can be individually for each core?

Tags: kernel, drivers

My understanding, p-state control freq & voltage for power efficiency.

The higher p-state, the more power efficiency.

Problem:

Intel p-state is a global setting for all cores or can be set individually for each core?

More info for p-state:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/power-management-states-p-states-c-states-and-package-c-states

Answer (score 3):

From a paper published in 2015: [An Energy Efficiency Feature Survey of the Intel Haswell Processor](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1109/IPDPSW.2015.70). It says "The FIVRs (see Section II-B) in Haswell-EP provide individual voltages for every core.
This enables per-core pstates (PCPS) [14] instead of one p-state for all cores as in
previous products.

The finer granularity of voltage and frequency domains enables energy-aware runtimes and operating systems to lower the power consumption of single cores while
keeping the performance of other cores at a high level."

So it seems like that before Intel Haswell Processor, there are no per-core based P-states. but **after Intel Haswell, there are per-core based P-states**.

Answer (score 0):

the coprocessor has package-based P-states, core-based C-states (which are sometimes referred to as CC-states) and package-based C-states (PC-states). It also has the capability to operate in Turbo mode3. **There are no per-core based P-states.**

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/power-management-states-p-states-c-states-and-package-c-states